# getting a result from PHP SQL but my "no result message" not showing

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL table as follows :

prim auto inc | hdate |nvs |vsa |**batch1number** | **batch2number** |

I am doing a sql query that`s aim is to compare the users input to column of interst 1 and column of interest 2. If either of the columns has the value I get the results into a select dropdown. - This part is working.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$userinputone=$_POST['abc']; 

$userinputone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$userinputone);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM handover WHERE batch1number  = '".$userinputone."' OR        

batch2number = '".$userinputone."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==0 ){

echo "</br></br></br></br></br><p> No Matching results found</p>";
}

else{     
echo "<select>";
echo "<option>" . $row['batch1number'] . $row['batch2number'] . "</option>";
echo "</select>";
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

However when I type (or not type!) in a blank entry my message "no matching results" is not output. 
Instead I get all of my results including blank ones in dropdowns. 
Also when I type in a value that does not match i just get a blank page and no message. 
I have looked up the empty() syntax suggested on a related question and tried applying round some of my variables. Im pretty sure it is to do with the $count == 0 part and have tried adding additional operators like || batch1number = '' && batch1number = '' - the query worked but I still did not get my error message.

If someone could please help me out and if time permits explain why I get these results I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logical error in the code. You'll never get into the cycle because `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` returns false from the beginning. What you need is:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$userinputone=$_POST['abc']; 

$userinputone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$userinputone);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM handover WHERE batch1number  = '".$userinputone."' OR        

batch2number = '".$userinputone."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==0 ){
    echo "</br></br></br></br></br><p> No Matching results found</p>";
}

else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<select>";
        echo "<option>" . $row['batch1number'] . $row['batch2number'] . "</option>";
        echo "</select>";
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

**Update** thanx to [Ohgodwhy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206267/ohgodwhy)

You may also want to go with improving `$userinputone`:

```
if (isset($_POST['abc'])) {
    $userinputone = $_POST['abc'];
}
else {
    $userinputone = false;
}
```

or simply

```
$userinputone = isset($_POST['abc'])? $_POST['abc'] : false;
```

and then wrapping the whole query thing into checking if `$userinputone` is really set:

```
if(isset($userinputone)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest `$userinputone = isset($_POST['abc'])? $_POST['abc'] : false;` and of course `if(isset($userinputone)){` at the very least. +1 anyway.

Comment: Cheers @Nordenheim & ohgodwhy. It has sorted my problem out. Nordenheim fixed the issue with the error message as asked. But adding the $userinputone = isset($_POST['abc']) fixed the blank query as I was still getting the empty selects. Again thanks very much

Comment: Im trying to +1 Ohgodwhy but do not seem to have the required authority yet. Maybe I ask too many questions. So a big thanks I hope will suffice.